# GCM:"error":"InvalidRegistration"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I download the sample "[https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git](http://hanlu.feng@stash.looppay.com/scm/man/tpdclient-android.git)".

I use example "gcmquickstart", I followed the [instruction](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) to get "google-service.json" and API_KEY.

However, when I run "GcmSender.java", there is an error `"error":"InvalidRegistration".`

I am very confused , because the Registration_
ID I got it from server and I can get the token from server.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you downloaded and added .json into your app folder ?

Comment: Yes, I added "google-services.json" under app module ,and the project and pass compile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, in "GcmSender.java", there are parameters in String[] args,

```
    if (args.length > 1 && args[1] != null) {
        jGcmData.put("to", args[1].trim());
    } else {
        jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/global");
    }
```

We should make sure "args[1].trim()" is a right parameter. I just add some random string, and after run

```
  jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/global");
```

It works

Thanks